# Javascript produced tables sometimes fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The last table and sometimes the table before as well will not load correctly sometimes which breaks the loop I have.

This error in my code started happening since I added the table creation part of my javascript.

My question is why because the way i have it works majority of the time but in these instances it does not. I am running it on jsfiddle.

Any help is appreciated.

Lastly I want to add in a picture of a star where the "new content" phrases are if you could help with that as well you would be of much help.

```
<html>

<head>  
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow()">
    <table id="myTable1" border="1"></table>
    <br>
    <table id="myTable2" border="1"></table>
    <br>
    <table id="myTable3" border="1"></table>
    <br>
     <h1 class="box">
    <table style="width:100%" id = "table1">
    </table>
    <br>
    <p id="time"></p>
    <span id="num1"></span>
    + <span id="num2"></span> =
    <input id="answer" type="text" size="3"/>
    <button onclick = "math1()">Check</button> 
</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

That is the HTML the Javascript will follow this.

```
window.onload = function uphigh() {
    document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
    num1 = parseInt(num1);
    num2 = parseInt(num2);
    var num3 = num1 + num2;
    insRow(2, 5, 'myTable1', num1);
    insRow(2, 5, 'myTable2', num2);
    insRow(4, 5, 'myTable3', num3);

};

function uphigh() {
    document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
    num1 = parseInt(num1);
    num2 = parseInt(num2);
    var num3 = num1 + num2;
    insRow(2, 5, 'myTable1', num1);
    insRow(2, 5, 'myTable2', num2);
    insRow(4, 5, 'myTable3', num3);

}

function math1() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
    num1 = parseInt(num1);
    num2 = parseInt(num2);
    var num0 = num1 + num2;
    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    answer = parseInt(answer);

    if (num0 == answer) {
        var things = ['Way to Go!!!', 'Congratulations!!!', 'Correct!!!', 'Your Doing Great!!!'];
        var thing = things[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
        alert(thing);
        deleteRow();
        uphigh();
        document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
    } else {
        alert("Incorrect answer!! \nPlease Try Again");
        document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
    }

}

function insRow(rows, col, tableId, num) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        var x = document.getElementById(tableId).insertRow();
        for (var i = 0; i < col; i++)
        var y = x.insertCell(0);
    }
    var row = parseInt(num / 5);
    var cols = num % 5;
    var x = document.getElementById(tableId).rows;
    if (row != 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            x = document.getElementById(tableId).rows;
            var y = x[j].cells;
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                y[i].innerHTML = "NEW CONTENT";
            }
        }
    }
    var y = x[row].cells;
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        y[i].innerHTML = "NEW CONTENT";
    }

}

function deleteRow() {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    document.getElementById('myTable1').deleteRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    document.getElementById('myTable2').deleteRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    document.getElementById('myTable3').deleteRow();
}
```

Building this website for helping children learn basic math.

Do not know how to add a link to fiddle.

Comment: Since you're already working on fiddler, post the link so that others can have a look at the working code.

Comment: Some JS DOM implementations refuse to insert `<tr>`s directly in a `<table>`, you need a `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>`. Check if this is not the case.